# MySQL single query multiple results

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to grab all the info I want through the following query. That is comment value where `status = 0` and SUM points where `status = 0` and where `status = 1`. Here is what I've got until now (I can't grab the comment value at this point)

```
SELECT
  IF(status = 0, comment, NULL) AS com,
  SUM(IF(status = 0, points, 0)) AS points1,
  SUM(IF(status = 1, points, 0)) AS points2
FROM `tablename`
  WHERE mid = $mid
  AND stage = 0
```

Table data:

```
+----+--------+--------+-----------+-----+------+
| id |   mid  | points |  comment  |stage|status|
+----+--------+--------+-----------+-----+------+
|  1 | 500    |   15   | Text here |  0  |   0  |
|  2 | 500    |   5    | Blablabla |  0  |   1  |
|  3 | 20     |   7    |           |  1  |   0  |
|  4 | 356    |   10   | More text |  0  |   2  |
|  5 | 9      |   0    |           |  1  |   0  |
|  6 | 52     |   5    | Text etc  |  0  |   1  |
|  7 | 520    |   13   | Texting   |  1  |   0  |
|  8 | 540    |   8    |           |  0  |   0  |
+----------------------------------------+------+
```

Results I am looking for:

- Where `mid = 500` and `stage = 0`
- IF `status = 0` get me the points (`15` in this case)
- IF `status = 1` get me the points (`5` in this case)
- IF `status = 0` get me the comment (`Text here` in this case)

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Is this better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using aggregation functions, then all columns should be aggregated.  I prefer `CASE` to `IF()` because the former is standard SQL:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN status = 0 THEN comment END) AS com,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status = 0 THEN points ELSE 0 END) AS points_0,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN points ELSE 0 END) AS points_1
FROM `tablename`
WHERE mid = $mid AND stage = 0 ;
```

Comments:

- This uses `GROUP_CONCAT()` in case more than one row matches the condition and has `status = 0`.
- The names of the "points" columns match the statuses being compared.

Comment: If there is only one row that matches the condition for the comment, what should I use instead of GROUP_CONCAT?

Comment: @Bill . . . You can use `MAX()` or `MIN()`.